# Fibonacci and Narayana relations ...

Tags: sequences-and-series

The quotient N(n)/F(n) , N being the Narayama sequence and F being the Fibonacci sequence seem to follow a nice trendline approx. e^(-0,1*n).

Does anyone know of such an exact relation?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by $F(n)$? The Narayana numbers that I know are *doubly* indexed: $N(n,k)$ is the number of Dyck paths from the origin to $\langle 2n,0\rangle$ with exactly $k$ peaks.

Comment: F(n) = A000045 (1,1,2,3,5,8,13...) N(n) = A00930 (1,1,1,2,3,4,6...)

Comment: Sorry! Look above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that

$$F_n=\left\lfloor\frac{\varphi^n}{\sqrt5}+\frac12\right\rfloor\;,$$

where $\varphi=\frac12\left(1+\sqrt5\right)$. According to OEIS A00930,

$$N_n=\left\lfloor dc^n+\frac12\right\rfloor\;,$$

where $c$ is the real root of $x^3-x^2-1$, and $d$ is the real root of $31x^3-31x^2+9x-1$; apparently $c=1.465571\ldots$ (more digits at OEIS A092526), and $d=0.611491991950812\ldots\;$. Thus,

$$\frac{N_n}{F_n}\approx d\sqrt5\left(\frac{c}{\varphi}\right)^n\approx 1.36734\cdot0.9057727^n\;.$$

It appears, then, that the ratio is proportional to about $e^{-0.098967}$, in close agreement with your empirical result.

Comment: Thanks - but the n's are missing in the suggested quotient.

Comment: @Jørgen: My apologies: I have *no* idea what I was thinking earlier. You are of course entirely correct, and your empirical estimate seems to be very close.

Comment: :-) Thank you very much!

Comment: @Jørgen: You’re very welcome, and I really am sorry about the mental hiccup.